# Random generation of fields using restrictions

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I would like to randomly fill the fields in a form, e.g. a driving license form. I can easily generate the values, but they usually doesn't make any sense. For example, the ending date of the form is randomly set before the starting date of the form. Is there any AI approach to generate randomly this fields using restrictions? How can I represent this restrictions? Can I use semantic nets?

Comment: AI doesn't naturally exist. It is artificial. Some body has to do it. There probably isn't one. Why don't you try to generate values that make sense?

Comment: Well, I already hardcoded the restrictions using a dependency network that I came up. But I guess that there must be an easier approach and that it has already an implemented software tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory you could of course use one or another concept from "traditional" research on AI. In your case for example it could work to let the system learn what *good* or *bad* values are in the context of your application. This could be accomplished via a reinforced learning approach or a artificial neural network if you want to let the system learn on its own, or maybe with some kind of an expert system. There might be several options. But be aware that implementing such a system might take some time...

However, since you have not shared many details on what you want to achieve, it's hard to tell what approach would work best in your case. From how I understand your question though it seems to me that any AI approach here might be an overkill if you simply want to check for the validity of some input parameters via traditional programming concepts (e.g. some basic checks whether input is correct or not).

HTH!

Comment: I was not thinking in something that learns restrictions to generate data and fill fields. I was thinking in something that stores the knowledge of the restrictions apriori and that could generate randomly many instances.